# Crashlytics gradle plugin doesn't find APK if running from Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I am about to configure Jenkins to promote builds to Fabric, but it's not looking in the right place, so that I get the following error when running this command:

```
gradle assembleStaging crashlyticsUploadDistributionApplication-Staging

Uploading /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/testPromoteBuildsOnCrashlytics/workspace/Application/build/outputs/apk/Application-staging.apk to Crashlytics...
 WARN - Crashlytics halted compilation because it can't find the specified file: /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/testPromoteBuildsOnCrashlytics/workspace/Application/build/outputs/apk/Application-staging.apk
```

Is there a way to tell crashlytics plugin where the build actually is?

Answer (score 3):

In your build.gradle you can add:

```
ext.betaDistributionApkFilePath = '/path/to/your/apk'
```

to the `crashlytics {}` block or your appropriate build variant's `{}` block.

Comment: is this path relative to the *app* folder? can you please give an example?

Comment: I found this example: https://gist.github.com/mandrachek/0a47a0d1e48aee860d6c

It allows you to set the APK path dynamically based on the variant's name and versionCode